# Java Spring MVC and Hibernate - notificate clients on a certain date

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, events, notifications

I am currently making an application and on my database I have a table that stores reservations of a room for a certain client. What I want is when the date of the reservation arrives it automatically send a notification to the client. My issue here is knowing on server side when does the date of the reservation is equal to the date of the current moment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use spring with quartz scheduler, here is the link of how to use [link] (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spring scheduler to check the current date with reserved date.If It matches then send the notification to client.